# JDS - Cuda implementation

Tags: c++, matrix, vectors, cuda

I am trying to implement the Jagged Diagonal Storage code in Cuda for Sparse Matrix - Vector multiplication. The code I wrote is as follows but I'm not sure about it:

```
__global__ jds_kernel(JDSMatrix jds, float * invector, float * outvector){
   int i = blockIdx.x * blockDime.x + threadIdx.x;
   int row = jds.rows[i];

   if (row < jds.numRows){
     float sum = 0.0f;
     for (nnz=0; nnz < jds.nnzperrow[row]; ++nnz){
        int idx = i + jds.iterPtr[nnz];
        int col = jds.colIdxs[idx];
        int val = jds.values[idx];
        sum += invector[col] * val;
     }

     output[row] = sum;
  }
}
```

Assuming that:

- `jds` is the jds matrix
- `invector` is the input vector
- `outvector` is the output vector
- `jds.numRows` is the number of rows in the jds matrix
- `jds.nnzperrow` is the number of non-zero entries in per row
- `jds.rows` are the rows
- `jds.iterPtr` is the iteration pointer
- `jds.colIdxs` is the column indexes
- `jds.values` are the values